# Accented characters from db not displaying right after server migration

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I'm storing strings in a mysql database, with `utf8_general_ci`.

I have accented characters, for example in phpmyadmin I have Ã‰ that will become É with a simple mysql `select` and php `print`.

But on my new server, after I copied all files and restored a dump with `mysql -p < dump.sql`, that stays Ã‰ when displayed on the page.

Other strings on the page are displayed normaly, only those comming from mysql have the problem. But I don't understand the cause as the files and database are the same that on my old server.

Comment: Note that the english for *bdd* (from the french *base de données*) is *db* (database)

Comment: @Cid sorry didn't think

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: If you want to discuss further, provide information such as:  Connection parameters, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, HEX() of the column (to check for "double encoding", `<meta>` if using HTML, etc.

Comment: Nobody wants to understand the the db is not in cause has this is the copy of a working db using the exact same php script. I checked the hex and there are the same on both.